# htaccess - restrict access unless from these 3 IP addresses

Tags: .htaccess, ip-address, restrict

I am trying to restrict my website whilst i am developing on it for all IP addresses except 3 in particular. In my htaccess file i have the following but I have just tried accessing on a different IP and it is not restricting it

```
## Restrict IP access
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from XX.XXX.XX.XXX
Allow from XX.XXX.XX.XXX
Allow from XX.XXX.XX.XXX
```

I've also tried the following which allows the first line but 403's the other 2 which suggests i can restrict/allow IP's it's just the code or order that is the issue?

```
<Limit GET POST>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from XX.XXX.XX.XXX
 allow from XX.XXX.XX.XXX
 allow from XX.XXX.XX.XXX
</Limit>
```

Comment: Does your apache config define a "AllowOverride Limit" so you are allowed to use Allow/Deny in your .htaccess?

Comment: Move `Deny from all` order at this end of your file maybe ?

Comment: moving Deny from all at the bottom gives no difference. When i then also change the Order to Allow,Deny i get a 403 forbidden on all IP's

Comment: @mp911de I've edited my question to include another method i tried which did do it for 1 of the IP's so i assume i am allowed?

Comment: Are you sure your .htaccess is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload Apache Configuration and check configuration using apachectl. Use command as:
    `apachectl configtest`
Once done with that, restart apache server or reload configuration. Command is:
    `service httpd reload`
OR
    `service httpd restart`

Also make sure that mod_authz_host is enabled in Apache Configuration. If all fails, use IP Tables to control entries.